# Como mover um ícone no mapa atrás da minha localização?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Estou a fazer um projeto que usa a API v2 do Google Maps. Nesse mapa aparece a minha localização que vai sendo atualizada assim que me movo. Coloquei um ícone com a imagem de polícia, e queria que esse ícone viesse atrás de mim cada vez que me movo, ou então se eu estiver parado continuar atrás de mim na mesma posição. Criei um método `stalK` que retorna um novo ponto mediante a minha localização e a localização da polícia. Tentei implementar, mas quando eu me movo o policial move-se também, mas apenas uma vez.

Deixo parte do meu código essencial para isso:

```
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
double longitude = location.getLongitude();

lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
longi = String.valueOf(longitude);

posCurrent = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
posAtuais.add(posCurrent);

posInicial = posAtuais.get(0);
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(posInicial));

map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(posCurrent, 19));

PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(mudaLinhaCor(heart_rate)).geodesic(true);
for (int z = 0; z < posAtuais.size(); z++) {
    LatLng point = posAtuais.get(z);
    options.add(point);
}
line = map.addPolyline(options);

Marker marker1 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(POLICE)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.police)));
    posAtuaisPolice.add(0, POLICE);

    policia = stalk(posCurrent,POLICE, map);
    posAtuaisPolice.add(policia);
    for(int i = 2; i< posAtuaisPolice.size(); i++){
        policia = stalk(posCurrent, posAtuaisPolice.get(i-1), map);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(policia)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.police)));
    }


 }

//A method that computes a new position
public LatLng stalk(LatLng player,LatLng police,GoogleMap mapView){
  Projection projection = mapView.getProjection(); 
  Point pointInicial = new Point(); //police
  pointInicial = projection.toScreenLocation(police);
  Point pointFinal = new Point(); //player
  pointFinal = projection.toScreenLocation(player);
  double y=0.2;
  int x=0;

if((pointInicial.x==pointFinal.x)){
    y=pointInicial.y+1;
}else{
    double m=(pointFinal.y-pointInicial.y)/(pointFinal.x-pointInicial.x);
    double b=pointInicial.y-(m*pointInicial.x);
    int i=1;

    while(y != (int)y){
        if(pointInicial.x<pointFinal.x){
            x=pointInicial.x+i;
            //System.out.println("entrou no x<xfnal: "+x);
        }
        else if(pointInicial.x>pointFinal.x){
            //System.out.println("entrou no x>xfnal");
            x=pointInicial.x-i;
        }
        y=m*x+b;
        //System.out.println("y: : "+y);
        i++;
    }
}
return projection.fromScreenLocation(new Point(x, (int) y)); 
}
```

Comment: Sugiro você debugar para entender o que está acontecendo. Sabe debugar no Android?

Comment: Sim sei, mas vai ser complicado uma vez que dentro de casa é difícil de apanhar sinal GPS

Comment: Você pode debugar no emulador e simular as posições GPS no DDMS. Veja [este tutorial](http://www.portalandroid.org/comunidade/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=865).

Comment: Obrigado pelo tutorial. Vou tentar ver se consigo resolver o problema.

Answer (score 2):

Cara, eu mudo a posição do ícone assim, esse método e bem simples e vc pode fazer varias modificações legais. Só e passar o LatLng para ele que o mesmo faz a magica. espero que lhe ajude

Obs.: o CircleOptions da um diferencial em apresentação. ;)

```
private MarkerOptions mMarkerOptions;
private CircleOptions mCircleOptions;
private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

private void updateMaps(LatLng latLng) {

        if (mMarkerOptions == null && mCircleOptions == null) {
            mMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .fromResource(R.drawable.img_mapa_ponto))
                    .title( "Titulo")
                    .snippet("Mensagem");

            mCircleOptions = new CircleOptions().center(latLng).radius(100)
                    .strokeWidth(3.0F)
                    .strokeColor(Color.parseColor("#700000FF"))
                    .fillColor(Color.parseColor("#300000FF"));

        } else {
            mMarkerOptions.position(latLng);
            mMarkerOptions.snippet("Mensagem");
            mCircleOptions.center(latLng);
            mCircleOptions.radius(100);

            mGoogleMap.clear();
        }

        mGoogleMap.addMarker(mMarkerOptions).showInfoWindow();
        mGoogleMap.addCircle(mCircleOptions);

        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17.0f));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Somente com esse trecho é bem complicado de dizer o que está acontecendo, seria necessário todo o código da classe que cuida da atualização do seu marker.

Mas pelo que você falou, de estar atualizando somente uma vez, procure no seu código se você fez corretamente o registro do listener da localização, que é chamado sempre que há uma mudança na localização.

E lembre-se de fazer a chamada manual para o seu método caso o usuário fique parado, pois nesse caso você não irá receber atualização de local, então tem que forçar a nova posição do seu ícone de polícia.

Se estiver em dúvida como receber essas atualizações, recomendo o guia da documentação oficial [Receiving Location Updates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html).